# jcarousel ie7 issue

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, jcarousel

I am having an issue with the jquery jcarousel plugin. If I don't use the "itemFallbackDimension" property I get an error that says "jCarousel: No width/height set for items. This will cause an infinite loop. Aborting...". If I do use the property I don't get any Javascript errors but all of the images stack vertically, they are not restricted in neither height nor width. When I press the next button they all scroll off the page.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#slideshow').jcarousel({
    scroll: 1,
    initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback,
    // This tells jCarousel NOT to autobuild prev/next buttons
    buttonNextHTML: null,
    buttonPrevHTML: null,
    itemLoadCallback: mycarousel_itemLoadCallback, //this is for loading the images via ajax
    itemFallbackDimension: 200, //stupid ie7 needs a fallback dimension
    visible: 1,
    vertical: false
});
});
```

Comment: I haven't used jCarousel but from a quick check of the examples don't you need `wrap: 'circular'`? or put the css to display it with `float` ?

Answer (score 0):

The itemFallback is only used if the dimensions can't be detected for some reason, that seems to be the case in ie7 so it uses the fallback. If you don't provide one, you get the error. So something is wrong with your css.

You need to set the width and height of the first parent of the carousel, This could give you the same error. [See this blog post](http://drayblog.gotdns.com/index.php/2011/03/31/jcarousel-no-width-height-set-for-items/)